# Node js path file

Tags: javascript, node.js

My csv file is in drive 'E' folder 'awais' and i am new to coding i cant access the file anybody can help me with relative path absolute path concept and how can i access this file

i am getting this error : "Unhandled rejection Error: File does not exist. Check to make sure the file path to your csv is correct."

````
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const csv = require('csvtojson');

const csvFile = ('/E/Awais/customer-data.csv');

csv()
.fromFile(csvFile).then ( (jsonObj) =>{
    console.log(jsonObj)
    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,'customer-data.json'),JSON.stringify(jsonObj,null,1),()=>{
        console.log(jsonObj)
});
})
```
````

Comment: You might wanna try `const csvFile = ('E:/Awais/customer-data.csv');`
That would be an absolute path.
If you want to use a relative path (meaning that the csv is located in a folder relative to where your code file is stored) you would need to let us know in which folder your code resides.
Alternatively (since you already imported path) you could also do `const csvFile = path.normalize('E:\\Awais\\customer-data.csv');`

Comment: Awais bhai path sahe se do "/E/Awais/customer-data.csv" ni ai ga .... "E/Awais/customer-data.csv" starting ma '/' ni lagay ga

Comment: Thanks DesperateEi Its working with absolute path. I was stuck with it and was not able to understand it. you did a great favour.

my source code file's location is in c/users/haisam zahid/csv-json/index.js
how i can i load with relative path from here

Comment: @AwaisZahid yar koshish kro k jo bhi file use krni ha wo node folder ma hi rakho phr "./" likho ge tu direct file access kr sako ge

Comment: @Saad Sohail got you bro

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try:

```js
const csvFile = ('E:/Awais/customer-data.csv');
```

That would be an absolute path. If you want to use a relative path (meaning that the csv is located in a folder relative to where your code file is stored) you would need to let us know in which folder your code resides. Alternatively (since you already imported path) you could also do:

```js
const csvFile = path.normalize('E:\\Awais\\customer-data.csv');
```